# Docusign "excludedDocuments" is not working

Tags: php, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignconnect

I am using composite method to generate envelope. I am trying to exclude some of the documents from "Witness" but witness able to view all the documents. Can anybody help here?
Below is my request:

```
{
"emailSubject": "Your recent purchase with XXXX.",
"emailBlurb": "Please sign your documents.",
"status": "sent",
"compositeTemplates": [{
    "compositeTemplateId": "1",
    "document": {
        "documentId": 1,
        "name": "Driving License ",
        "fileExtension": "html",
        "documentBase64": "<base64 encoded data>",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
    },
    "inlineTemplates": [{
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [{
                "email": "customer@sample.com",
                "name": "Customer Name",
                "recipientId": "f51aeab9ab1dfe21fbc45b4c74e6d73b",
                "clientUserId": "1000",
                "roleName": "Sender",
                "routingOrder": 1,
                "defaultRecipient": true
            }]
        },
        "sequence": "2"
    }]
}, {
    "compositeTemplateId": "2",
    "document": {
        "documentId": 2,
        "name": "Sales Contract",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "transformPdfFields": "true",
        "documentBase64": "base64 encoded data"
    },
    "inlineTemplates": [{
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [{
                "email": "customer@sample.com",
                "name": "Customer Name",
                "recipientId": "f51aeab9ab1dfe21fbc45b4c74e6d73b",
                "roleName": "Sender",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "clientUserId": "1000",
                "defaultRecipient": "true",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                        "documentId": 2,
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorXOffset": "50",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-40",
                        "anchorString": "Date Purchaser Signed",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "required": "true"
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                "email": "manager@sample.com",
                "name": "Manager",
                "recipientId": "3",
                "roleName": "Dealer",
                "routingOrder": "3",
                "clientUserId": "1000",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                        "documentId": 2,
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorXOffset": "50",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-15",
                        "anchorString": "Trader Authorised Employee Signature",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "required": "true"
                    }],
                    "dateSignedTabs": [{
                        "documentId": 2,
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorXOffset": "50",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-15",
                        "anchorString": "Date Employee Signed",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "required": "true",
                        "value": "19\/09\/2023"
                    }]
                }
            }],
            "witnesses": [{
                "email": "witness@sample.com",
                "name": "Witness 1",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "Witness 65580212 for 70485785",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "witnessFor": 2,
                "status": "created",
                "recipientType": "witness",
                "clientUserId": "1000",
                "excludedDocuments": [1, 3],
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                        "documentId": 2,
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorXOffset": "50",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-15",
                        "anchorString": "Witness Signature",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "required": "true",
                        "value": "Akhil"
                    }],
                    "textTabs": [{
                        "documentId": 2,
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorXOffset": "50",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-15",
                        "anchorString": "Witness Name",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "required": "true",
                        "value": "Akhil"
                    }]
                }
            }]
        },
        "sequence": "2"
    }]
}, {
    "compositeTemplateId": "3",
    "document": {
        "documentId": 3,
        "name": "Document 3"
    },
    "serverTemplates": [{
        "sequence": "1",
        "templateId": "<Docusign template Id>"
    }],
    "inlineTemplates": [{
        "recipients": {
            "signers": [{
                "email": "customer@sample.com",
                "name": "Customer",
                "recipientId": "f51aeab9ab1dfe21fbc45b4c74e6d73b",
                "roleName": "Sender",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "clientUserId": "1000",
                "defaultRecipient": "true",
                "tabs": {
                    "textTabs": [{
                        "documentId": 3,
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorXOffset": "5",
                        "anchorYOffset": "-2",
                        "anchorString": "\/cn1\/",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "required": "true",
                        "value": "Siemens"
                    }],
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                        "documentId": 3,
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorXOffset": "15",
                        "anchorYOffset": "1",
                        "anchorString": "\/cussign1\/",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "required": "true"
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                "email": "manager@sample.com",
                "name": "Manager",
                "recipientId": "3",
                "roleName": "Dealer",
                "routingOrder": "3",
                "clientUserId": "1000",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{
                        "documentId": 3,
                        "pageNumber": "1",
                        "anchorXOffset": "15",
                        "anchorYOffset": "1",
                        "anchorString": "\/dealersign1\/",
                        "anchorUnits": "pixels",
                        "required": "true"
                    }]
                }
            }]
        },
        "sequence": "2"
    }]
}]
```

}

I am trying to exclude documentId's 1 and 3 from witness of document 2.But Witness able to view excluded documents too. Is it because of Anchor tag which i specified?

Comment: Can you try to make all documentId a string like "2" and not an integer like 2?

Comment: It didn't worked @InbarGazit

Comment: ok, one other idea I have. You have a templateId for a ServerTemplate, does this template have any documents? Is it possible it has the same document(s) you have included here and that's why they show up?